# Optimize the use of pyspark inside classes - functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to figure out how to optimize the use of pyspark inside classes - functions.

```
    class preprocessing:
        def df_a():
            df_a = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true")\
                .csv(df_a_name, sep=r',')
            df_a = df_a.drop(*['sd2', 'sd3', 'd28_98_other'])
            return df_a

        def df_b():
            df_b = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true")\
                .csv(df_b_name, sep=r';')
            df_b = df_b.select('idu', 'aaa', 'zzz')
            df_b = df_b.withColumn('zzz', fu.regexp_replace('zzz', ',', 
                '.').cast(FloatType()))
            return df_b
   
        def variables():
            df_a = dataframe_preprocessing.df_a()
            df_b = dataframe_preprocessing.df_b()
            # operations to create a dataframe containing all the unique variables
            variables = variables_a.union(variables_b)
            return variables
```

Probably it's overkill to use function only to read a file, in reality more things are happening within the functions.

**Do I need to use .cache() at any point? If yes, where into the code? The idea is to optimize the computation of variables (called multiple times later on in the script). Thanks**

Comment: Due to Spark's lazy evaluation, if you don't call `df.show()`, `df.count()`, `df.write()` etc, no computation will proceed and there is no point of caching.

Comment: By the way there are lots of undefined variables in the code snippet, please improve it